# I have used "cors" but I found "Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked". Why?

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I have an express API running and when I make a request I get this message.

```sh
Error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9000/api/courses' from origin
'http://localhost:4222' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I am using `cors` in my API here is my code:

```js
import * as express from 'express';
import {Application} from "express";
import {getAllCourses, getCourseById} from "./get-courses.route";
import {searchLessons} from "./search-lessons.route";
import {loginUser} from "./auth.route";
import {saveCourse} from "./save-course.route";

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app: Application = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.route('/api/login').post(loginUser);
app.route('/api/courses').get(getAllCourses);
app.route('/api/courses/:id').put(saveCourse);
app.route('/api/courses/:id').get(getCourseById);
app.route('/api/lessons').get(searchLessons);

const httpServer = app.listen(9000, () => {
    console.log("HTTP REST API Server running at http://localhost:" + httpServer.address().port);
});
```

Kindly assist me. I appreciate all responses. Thanks Ahead.

Comment: And your server running on 4222?

Comment: Node server running on port: 9000 and frontent(angular)  running on port: 4222

Comment: No, I haven't set anything else apart from this code.

Comment: Hm, I don't see anything in your example code that services `api/courses`, though. How is that not a 404?

Comment: @mike, Now I have update all code. please check again

Comment: You're using `app.route`, which is a Router object, so you probably need to give tell that router to `.use(cors())`, rather than the app. (see https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#app-route and https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router)

Comment: yes, I have tried like..app.route('/api/login').all(cors()).post(loginUser);
but this was not work for me

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: very hard to replicate this issue on other env. Working fine when tried with es5 js syntax. Can you try without using router ? expose one route at main file itself and try.

Answer (score 1):

Give an origin to it

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://yourapp.com'
}));
```