# React making axios get, returns error: CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to make an axios get request, but i am getting corse policy error. I am kinda new to axios, this is what i tried:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let url =
      'http://18.189.49.66:3000/api/calculate/' +
      props.type +
      '/' +
      height +
      '/' +
      width;

    var config = {
      headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
    };

    axios.get(url, config).then(_result => {
      console.log('Duomenys: ' + JSON.stringify(_result));
    });

}, [length, width, height]);
```

In my `app.js` on node.js express i have these lines:

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

And here is the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://18.189.49.66:3000/api/calculate/LF/80/200'
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

xhr.js:172 GET http://18.189.49.66:3000/api/calculate/LF/80/200 net::ERR_FAILED dispatchXhrRequest
@ xhr.js:172 xhrAdapter
@ xhr.js:11 dispatchRequest
@ dispatchRequest.js:59 Promise.then (async) request
@ Axios.js:53 Axios.<computed>
@ Axios.js:68 wrap
@ bind.js:9 (anonymous)
@ Calculator.js:113 commitHookEffectList
@ react-dom.development.js:22030 commitPassiveHookEffects
@ react-dom.development.js:22064 callCallback
@ react-dom.development.js:336 invokeGuardedCallbackDev
@ react-dom.development.js:385 invokeGuardedCallback 
@ react-dom.development.js:440 flushPassiveEffectsImpl 
@ react-dom.development.js:25392 unstable_runWithPriority 
@ scheduler.development.js:697 runWithPriority$2 
@ react-dom.development.js:12149 flushPassiveEffects 
@ react-dom.development.js:25361 flushDiscreteUpdates 
@ react-dom.development.js:24359 finishEventHandler 
@ react-dom.development.js:1384 batchedEventUpdates 
@ react-dom.development.js:1418 dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem 
@ react-dom.development.js:5894 attemptToDispatchEvent 
@ react-dom.development.js:6010 dispatchEvent 
@ react-dom.development.js:5914 ListPicker._handleMouseUp createError.js:16 

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:81)
```

My backend:

...
    var cors = require('cors');
    ...

```
app.use(cors());
```

...

**How should i edit my request?**

Comment: If you have access to the  backend server end-point you can use a package called cors to solve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin in reactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51577526/no-access-control-allow-origin-in-reactjs)

Comment: According to your comment on one of the answers you have control over the backend which is written in express and you're already using `app.use(cors());`. The question now is: are you calling that line *before* your route setup? Or after?

Comment: The strange thing is if i use axios in class component I don't have problem with cors policy. It only appears in this functional component.

Comment: All else being equal, `app.use(cors());` should do the job. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` is a **response** header. Don't put it on the request.

Comment: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' without it i still get error.

Comment: It looks like the route is broken because setting up cors doesn't help if the server doesn't send anything back. Try going to http://18.189.49.66:3000/api/calculate/LF/80/200 and you'll see there's no reply.

Comment: sorry wrong example, http://18.189.49.66:3000/api/calculate/lfp/90/200

Comment: I think problem is because LF is in upper case letters

Comment: Guys Thanks for help, problem was that letters was in upper case, my mistake :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that in URL which i was calling letters were upper case, that caused error.

Answer (score 0):

For those ones who are learning React and Axios and met this problem, here is an easy solution, download Chrome Extension, [**Allow-Control-Allow-Origin plugin**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en-US)

And turn it on..Boom..
Here is the original article introducing CORS error,
https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9
There are so many answers with the same errors but different backend languages so the solutions varied, I tried a few and none was working even adding header Access-Control-Allow-Origin to both PHP config file and apache.
Hope this helps you to continue your project.

Answer (score -1):

To solve the problem, you have to create a proxy server by nodejs and express(or anything else can help in proxying). If you are using the create-react-app, you can follow this tutorial:

[Proxying API requests in development](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

Answer (score -2):

You need to add cors in the backend - Basically you will have to tell the backend the url from which you will be requesting through

[I have used "cors" but I found "Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked". Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60219757/i-have-used-cors-but-i-found-access-to-xmlhttprequest-has-been-blocked-why/60221266#60221266)

OR use

https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Comment: This is not an answer since you dont know if he/she has access to the backend

Comment: Hi, in my app.js on node.js express i have these lines:
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

Comment: @Emilis That is absolutely vital information and needs to be added properly to the question.

Comment: You have to pass the url from which you are requesting this way - app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://yourapp.com'
}));